# No PL/SQL translation for the bindtype given for this bind variable

Tags: oracle11g, oraclereports

I am working on reports oracle 11g and applying formula as follows

```
function CF_CLEAR_EMP_NAMEFormula return Char is
    V_EMP_DESC VARCHAR2(1500);
BEGIN
    pkg_lkp.p_emp(:P_Lang,TO_CHAR(:emp_serno1),V_EMP_DESC);     
    RETURN INITCAP(V_EMP_DESC); 
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

and when I compile it gives me this error I checked :emp_serno1 type and formula type and no clue what happens when I change :emp_serno1 to :emp_serno which in other query it compiles but that's not what I want.

> no PL/SQL translation for the bindtype given for this bind variable

I checked the error description on the internet:

**Cause**: A host variable was passed (by an
Oracle Precompiler program, for example) to PL/SQL for binding. However, its
datatype is not compatible with any PL/SQL datatype. So, the binding
failed.
**Action**: Change the datatype of the host
variable to make it compatible with a PL/SQL datatype.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

“No PL/SQL translation for the blind type given for this bind variable” : I think this is a report Builder 11g bug.

When you get this error :

1. Save report
2. Close the existing report
3. Re-open report and compile it

After that your report will be run without errors.